# Using BeautifulSoup, is it possible to move to the parent tag when using the search for text function?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to move from the current position in the DOM up and down when only the text is an common identifier?

```
<div>changing text</div>
    <div>fixed text</div>
```

How to get the text `changing text` when searching for the `fixed text` and moving up to parent div?

What I tried:

```
x = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('fixed text')).parent

AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Comment: What happened with your attempt?

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'parent'....sorry, I'll add it to the question

Comment: `findAll` returns `ResultSet` - a list of elements. You want to do the operation on the elements inside the result set.

Comment: @BitByBit check my edited answer

Comment: @ TalesPadua It does not work because even if they are still only siblings you still have to move first to parents. I don't know why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program might do what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '<body><div>changing text</div><div>fixed text</div><body>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

x = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('fixed text'))[0].parent.previous_sibling

assert x.text == 'changing text'
```

Comment: I like, but considering this is `find_all`, a list comprehension may be in order `divs = [elem.previous_sibling for elem in soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('fixed text'))]`

Comment: It works, but I don't quite get it. As Tales has mentioned, these are actually siblings so why are we involving parents here?

Comment: @BitByBit - it shouldn't work if they are siblings. But we don't have enough of your doc to figure it out. I posted an example to make a list of divs... does that work?

Comment: `.parent` is required because `findAll` returns the string node, not the `<div>` node. If you want `findAll` to return the `<div>` node, try: `x = soup.body.findAll('div', text=re.compile('fixed text'))[0].previous_sibling`

Comment: @tdelaney You were close, Rob is right. `divs = [elem.parent.previous_sibling for elem in soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('fixed text'))]`

Answer (score 1):

The error you are having is due to call `parent` in a ResultSet, a list of results. If you need to have multiple results, try:

```
x = soup.body.find_all(text=re.compile('fixed text'))
for i in x:
    previous_div = i.previous_sibling
```

If you doesnt want to find multiple results, just change find_all to find:

```
x = soup.body.find(text=re.compile('fixed text')).previous_sibling
```

Note that I replace parent to previous_sibling, as the divs are in the same level

Comment: You changed this to only find a single element. OP is using `findAll` and presumably wants to do processing on multiple nodes.

Comment: Yes, but the error OP is having is due to use parent in a ResultSet. I will edit to clarify