# BeautifulSoup4 extract multiple data from TD tags within TR

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

## Using beautifulsou 4 to scrape a HTML table.

To display values from one of the table rows and remove any empty `td` fields.
The source being scraped shares classes=''

So is there any way to pull the data form just one row? using

`data-name ="Georgia"`  in the **html** source below

Using: beautifulsoup4

### Current code

```
 import bs4 as bs from urllib.request import FancyURLopener

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'My new User-Agent'   # Set this to a string you want for your user agent

myopener = MyOpener()
sauce = myopener.open('')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

#table = soupe.table
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all_next('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

#### HTML SOURCE

```
        <tr>
          <td class="text--gray">

            <span class="save-button" data-status="unselected" data-type="country" data-name="Kazakhstan">&#9733;</span>

            Kazakhstan
          </td>

          <td class="text--green">
            81
          </td>

          <td class="text--green">
            9
          </td>

          <td class="text--green">
            12.5
          </td>

          <td class="text--red">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--red">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--red">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--blue">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--yellow">
            0
          </td>
        </tr>







        <tr>
          <td class="text--gray">

            <span class="save-button" data-status="unselected" data-type="country" data-name="Georgia">&#9733;</span>

            Georgia
          </td>

          <td class="text--green">
            75
          </td>

          <td class="text--green">
            0
          </td>

          <td class="text--green">
            0
          </td>

          <td class="text--red">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--red">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--red">
            0
          </td>
          <td class="text--blue">
            10
          </td>
          <td class="text--yellow">
            1
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Please update the question from the sample html what should be your expected output?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking.  But I removed all of the html im not trying scrape.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like:

```
tr.find_all('td',{'data-name' : True})
```

That should find any td that contains data name. I could be reading your question all wrong though.

Comment: @CompassSolutions So you are just looking to pull out a single td. Does the data-name value change or are you trying to get specific ones? If it is static you can use tr.find_all('td',{'data-name' : 'value you are looking for' })

Comment: Trying to get only the data from one data-name which is the one labeled data-name='Georgia' and remove any td fileds with no data

Comment: @CompassSolutions I'm understanding what you are looking for now. What I would say that you could do a for loop like you have and look at the first td of each tr. If the data structure is the always the same you can do a check to see if contains the value you are looking for. Something like check = td[0] and use some comparing magic. Then you can nest another statement with if td.text() != 0 then blah else pass. There might be better ways of doing this but I'm still learning.

Comment: @CompassSolutions https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980998/13132071 using something like the top answer will get you what you want. Then just do a check if the tss are empty